# Git - Remove Sensistive Information In Project File

Tags: git, github

I have a script that connects to the database for my game. Now this script has database a database username and password, I would like to hide this information from the github repo. I want to put the code up on github. But I'm lazy and don't like to bother with obfuscating the password fields in my code. As I don't want my local repo and the remote repo getting out of sync. Is there any way to hide these fields on commit.

Comment: Files that contain passwords, even if they're "obfuscated" should not be in your repo.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm doing an open-source programming contest and I have to have all the source code in the repo.

Comment: If your open-source app can connect to the database, then anyone will be able to connect to the database. If that's not what you want, then the passwords will have to come from some source other than your app.

Comment: @KeithThompson How would I go about providing a password from some source other than my app?

Comment: In any of a number of ways, depending on the app. It could prompt for a password from the user (not always possible), it could read it from a secured configuration file that's distributed separately from the application sources, etc. If the app creates the database, it could generate the password the first time it runs and store it securely. It's impossible to be more specific without more information about how your game works. (And I'm no security expert; don't take my word for any of this.)

Answer (score 1):

How about having the script read the password from a config file, and either don't commit that or commit a dummy config file? I've done so myself with a Python script that needs to connect as myself to an external database.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Would this be added to the git hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider placing the password in a local file onto the machine on which your game is supposed to run.

- Make sure the file is located outside the htdocs directory of your browser, but is still readable by the web server user (e.g. apacheuser). This will allow nobody to view the password file through the file's URL, which would be unsafe. But this still allows your script, which is probably run through the webserver, to access the local file. Of course, it should be located outside of the code file tree you keep in sync with your github repository.
- Place the password you want to hide from github into that directory. For enhanced security, consider using an encryption mechanism. Having plain passwords on the server could be a security risk. Be sure that the file is safely encoded (preferably utf-8) and check that there is no newline character around. If there is and you can't get rid of it, you will need to strip `\n` from the password variable prior to using it.
- In your script, include this or equivalent code (example in python) before the password is required for the first time:

  ```
  pwstring = str()
  with open('passwordfilepath', r) as pwfile:
     pwstring = pwfile.read()
  ```
- After this, you might want to remove newline characters. For example, you can use the following for that:

  ```
  pwstring = pwstring.rstrip('\n')
  ```

  Also, if you chose to save an encrypted password, you will need to add a decryption function or something similar.